# How to return all values of a column as null except one column value in SQL script?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I want to return only one column value and other column values as null from database. how can i do that in SQl script? also have to make values of not nullable fields to null while retrieving

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT column, cast(null as int) as intcolumnexample, cast(null as nvarchar) as stringcolumnexample FROM tbl
```

You want to cast ideally so that it's a column of the correct data type.